# Is it allowed to ask two close questions to proof verification in MSE with different solutions?

Tags: discussion, support, allowed-questions, solution-verification, proof-verification

I asked a question [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3546435/460967), but I failed the solution I made. Then I made an [almost completely different attempt](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556795/460967) to eliminate all errors. I re-posted the question, since editing the old question will override the existing answer. Does the MSE rules allow me to do this? (I got downvote) But, there is a truth. That is the extreme effort I made.

By the way, can I send new solution for questions I have previously failed?

Comment: You got *one* downvote. Big deal. Probably someone's cat walked across his keyboard.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ohh, my english is insufficient so it could be misunderstanding. Taking Downvote is extremely natural. My concern is, did I act against the rules?

Comment: Sorry, it looked like you were concluding that m.se didn't like your question on the basis of it receiving a downvote.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for comment.